# Parallel Universe Moving Backwards in time

Tags: arrow-of-time, multiverse

We know that different parallel universes- if they truly exist - are governed by different sets of laws. But, Could there be a parallel universe that is moving back in time(?) - in different direction the flow of time in our universe?

Comment: How does one measure whether something in one universe is the same direction as in another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens at the interface between two universes with opposite thermodynamic arrows of time?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61113/)

Answer (score 1):

**We know that different parallel universes- if they truly exist - are governed by different sets of laws.**

No we don't. If parallel universes exist, we know *nothing* about them. They could have the same laws, different laws, or no laws.

**in different direction the flow of time in our universe - ?**

The only thing that really defines the "direction" of time in our universe (rather than the rate) is entropy, which increases over time. So a universe could exist where entropy decreases over time under a different set of laws, until it reaches 0 entropy.